# An introduction to Lane-Riesenfeld algorithms

Tags: algorithm, geometry, subdivision, computational-geometry

I am looking for a good introduction to Lane-Riesenfeld algorithms, which are a family of subdivision methods for generating uniform B-splines. Any suggestions?

*Note.* This is a copy of [the question I asked on Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428101/an-introduction-to-lane-riesenfeld-algorithms). One of the users there suggested this site might have more answers to offer.

Comment: Original question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1428101/an-introduction-to-lane-riesenfeld-algorithms